# Undefined index whereas the index exists

Tags: php, arrays

```
print_r($address['Country']);
echo $address['Country']['name'];
```

Here is what I get for the print_r:

```
Array
(
    [Country] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => US
            [name] => United States
        )
)
```

And for the echo:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: name

How is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried `$address['Country']['Country']['name']`?

Comment: Try `print_r($address)` and it should become quite clear.

Comment: Thanks guys, got it. I guess I still need some time to understand the weird way CakePHP works ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `$address['Country']` is really and indeed

```
Array
(
    [Country] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => US
            [name] => United States
        )
)
```

Then your `name` should be in `$address['Country']['Country']['name']`, not sure why your array is that convoluted, but anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Its certain that you are having a three dimensional array. Try `$address['Country']['Country']['name']`.